# Detectar en que elemento html se ha hecho click con jQuery

Tags: jquery

Si tengo por ejemplo varios `<span>` y le hago click a uno como puedo, con jquery saber en cual he hecho click? Siendo las ID de los elementos numerados automáticamente con `item_<?php echo $i; ?>` ?

Es decir, yo quiero que al hacer en el span con `id=item_2` me haga por ejemplo un `alert.()` "has hecho click en item_2"

```html
<div id="items_en_uso">
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_1">Hola</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_2">adios</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_3">buenas</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_4">malas</span><br><br>
</div>
```

EDITO:

Los spans son añadidos al hacer click en otro elemento con

```
$("#clikeable").click(function(){
   $("#items_en_uso").append("<span id='item"+count+"'>Hola</span>");
});
```

Si los spans están puestos a mano (no por jquery) si que funciona, pero si los añado con jquery al hacerles click, no me funciona... Como puedo arreglar esto?

Comment: Por qué una recompensa, teniendo una respuesta aceptada?

Comment: La he aceptado después de poner la recompensa, no me deja darle la recompensa aún a @Muriano pero cuadno pueda se la daré, porque el ha respondido después de poner dicha recompensa.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

el método .click de jQuery solo funciona con elementos que ya están en el DOM cuando el documento se carga. Para vincular eventos a elementos agregados al DOM de forma dinámica, usa el método .on sobre un elemento contenedor y filtra por el selector del elemento de interés.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '#items_en_uso span', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
  })
})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="items_en_uso">
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_1">Hola</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_2">adios</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_3">buenas</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_4">malas</span><br><br>
<span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_5">SPAN DENTRO DEL DIV, SI ME HACES CLICK MOSTRARÉ UN ALERT CON MI ID</span><br><br>
</div>

<span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_4">SPAN POR FUERA DEL DIV, SI ME HACES CLICK NO VOY HA HACER NADA</span><br><br>
```

Edición: Tal como comentan, el código se puede mejorar más.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('body #items_en_uso').on('click', 'span', function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'))
      })
    })
```

De esta manera, optimizas la parte en la que jQuery filtra el elemento objeto del evento.

Comment: +1 por usar **delegated events** ya que reducen la sobrecarga de la página al enlazar un event handler sólo a un elemento, en éste caso `body`. Sin embargo me parece más correcto enlazarlo de la siguiente forma:  `$('body #items_en_uso').on('click', 'span', function()` ya que así el evento sólo tiene que hacer el bubble up a un elemento del span al `#items_en_uso` en lugar de tener que escalar hasta el elemento `body` en el DOM

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @david_rprada, ya he actualizado la respuesta acorde a ello.

Comment: En la edición, puedes quitar `body` en el selector y seguiría funcionado igual

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, gracias por la información.

Answer (score 9):

Con este códdigo puedes realizar lo que deseas, simplemente está a la escucha de todos los elementos de tipo *span* dentro de tu `div` con *id* "*items_en_uso*" en tu código (previniendo hacer click en otros elementos de tipo *span* que estén por fuera) y devuelve el valor del atributo *id* mediante el objeto `$(this)`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#items_en_uso span').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
  })
})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="items_en_uso">
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_1">Hola</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_2">adios</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_3">buenas</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_4">malas</span><br><br>
<span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_5">SPAN DENTRO DEL DIV, SI ME HACES CLICK MOSTRARÉ UN ALERT CON MI ID</span><br><br>
</div>

<span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_4">SPAN POR FUERA DEL DIV, SI ME HACES CLICK NO VOY HA HACER NADA</span><br><br>
```

Comment: Se puede hacer eso mismo pero solo para los elementos que están dentro del div `id="items_en_uso"`?

Comment: Bueno, como está mi respuesta funciona para hacer click en todos los `span` que estén dentro `<div id="items_en_uso"></div>` ¿te refieres a poder hacer click en cualquier elemento dentro de dicho `div`?

Comment: Es decir, si hay spans que están fuera de ese div no se vean afectados por esta función. Tan solo que sean "clickeables" los que están dentro de dicho div.

Comment: Revisa bien mi respuesta, es lo que buscas, puse un span por fuera y al darle `click` no hace nada, solo se ven afectados los que están DENTRO del `div`

Comment: @PavloB. - Con el selector `*` puedes seleccionar cualquier elemento dentro del `'#items_en_uso` -> `$('#items_en_uso *').on('click', function() {
    
    alert($(this).prop('id'));
  });`

Answer (score 3):

Puedes realizarlo tomando como referencia los elementos que empiezan por ese id en concreto (los que empiezan por `item_`) con el selector `^=` y después hacer referencia al elemento que has pulsado con la palabra reservada `this`.

De esta manera, una vez hayas detectado el elemento que ha sido pulsado y que tiene un id que empieza por `item_`, podrás obtener su atributo con la función `attr('id')` del mismo.

```js
$("span[id^=item_]").click(function() {
  console.log("Has pulsado el elemento: " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items_en_uso">
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_1">Hola</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_2">adios</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_3">buenas</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_4">malas</span><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo hago lo siguiente para detectar a que elemento de una lista se hace click, espero te pueda servir.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ListPage").click(function (e) {
        var id = e.target.id;
        alert(id); // Mostrar ID solo para verificar que sea correcto
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar un *selector* para todos los elementos de tipo *span*

En ese caso tendrias que reemplazar el *span* por el tipo de elemento que quieres acceder

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("span").click(function(){
    console.log(this.attr('id'));
  });

});
```

```html
<div id="items_en_uso">
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_1">Hola</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_2">adios</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_3">buenas</span><br><br>
  <span style="background:#c9c9c9;padding:3px;" id="item_4">malas</span><br><br>
</div>
```