# Obtener url de miniatura de video, youtube

Tags: javascript

Deseo que al hacer clic en un miniatura de los videos de YouTube, aparezca un alert con la url que cargara el video.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logre agregar eventos gracias a [estas respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/evento-click-en-todos-los-elementos), pude obtener las url satisfactoriamente también. Sin embargo cuando hago click, en lugar de aparecer la url correspondiente al video, aparece la ultima url que se itera.

```
function addclik(){
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('.large-media-item-thumbnail-container');
for(video of videos){
    video.addEventListener('click', function(){hizoclick(video.href)});
    console.log(video.href)
    }
}

function hizoclick(url){
    console.log(url)
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán aquí abajo la url que se mostro en la consola, no es la que corresponde al video sino a el últimos de ellos.
Antes creaba una variable, le asignaba `video.href` y luego la pasaba como parámetro para la función, ahí me di cuenta de que la variable se cambiaba en la ultima iteración, pensaba que de esta forma (pasando directamente  el `video.href`)ya no ocurría lo mismo, pero vuelve a pasar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo lograrlo, gracias por leer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema lo tienes en que cada vez que el bucle de addclick agrega el eventlisener, lo está haciendo a un elemento que tiene sólo la clase '.large-media-item-thumbnail-container', por lo tanto, lo está haciendo a todos los elementos cada vez, variando el valor de video.ref en cada pasada. Como resultado obtienes que el evento funciona, pero para todos los videos tienes la misma url(la de la última pasada).
Yo en lugar de añadir un evento, le añadiría la propiedad "onclick" a cada elemento independientemente, de esa forma te aseguras que cada evento click es exclusivo para cada video.
El código quedaría así:

```
function addclik(){
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('.large-media-item-thumbnail-container');
for(video of videos){
    video.setAttribute("onclick", "hizoclick('" + video.href + "')");
    console.log(video.href)
    }
}

function hizoclick(url){
    console.log(url)
}
```

Comment: Funciono, solo tuve que agregar la "h" en ('" + video.ref + "')"), gracias.

Comment: Sorry, es que tengo dedos como morcillas, lo rectifico para futuras consultas.

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: Un placer, para eso estamos ;-)